# Как обрабатывать url функцией wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Так вопрос! Хочу , что бы если юзер запрашивал например /some-url его обрабатывала бы функция worpress. Нужен такой себе контроллер. Задача стоит такая: Нужно сформировать url на основании url будет формироваться контент, но страниц созданных нету и не будет.

Ковырялся с query_var , пробовал банально

```
function my_fun_witch_router() {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/some-url') { 
echo 'Hello'; 
} 
add_action('init' , 'my_fun_witch_router');
```

Получаю 404 ошибку и поверх ответ если url совпадает. А мне нужно формировать отдельную страницу. Спасибо.

Еще так пробую:

```
function cvk_year_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^foobar?','index.php?is_foobar_page=1');
  set_query_var('is_foobar_page' , 1);
}

add_action('init' , 'cvk_year_rule');

function cl_year_view() {
  if(get_query_var('is_foobar_page')){
    echo 'done';
  }
}

add_action('init' , 'cl_year_view');
```

Answer (score 1):

Для создания таких "виртуальных страниц" я использую следующий код:

```
add_action( 'init', 'virtual_page' );

public function virtual_page() {
    $page_slug = 'some_url';

    $uri  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( '/' . trailingslashit( $page_slug ) === trailingslashit( $path ) ) {
        include 'virtual_page.php';
        exit;
    }
}
```

И в файле `virtual_page.php` делаю то, что нужно. Этот код легко расширить на любое количество виртуальных страниц.